# Attaching new SQL Server database to 2008 R2. Error: 5172. Converting database to be compatible with older version

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been provided with a database iI wish to query. However, given the error message and some research, I believe that it was formed in a newer version of `SQL Server`. See error message attached below.

Can someone guide me with the appropriate steps for converting this database to make it compatible with `SQL Server 2008 R2`. Bearing in mind I do not have access to a newer version of `SQL Server` to try an import/export or to generate scripts. What third party applications would be appropriate for this task?

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Detailed error message:

[image]

Comment: Download an evaluation, express, or developer edition of a later version and and use that? But I think the error message is telling you it is corrupted not necessarily a product version issue.

Comment: I agree with Martin. What makes you believe this is based on product editions? I have seen the error for newer database versions attempting to be accessed by older SSMS and it isn't close to what you've provided.

Comment: Hi both, Yes it appears to be a database problem, thanks for the insight.